# Tensorflow: Using a value in a tensor as a parameter

Tags: tensorflow

I want to calculate the loss function in my DNN in a different way depending on the value of the label.

Conceptually it's something like this:

```
def loss(logits, labels):

    if labels[0] == 0:
        return loss_function_1(logits, labels)
    else:
        return loss_function_2(logits, labels)
```

Obviously this won't work because I can't do this comparison on a tensor object. I also can't use `eval()`, because I get an error that the network is not defined. Do I have another option?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#cond) construct for this :

```
tf.cond(labels[0] == 0, lambda: loss_function_1(logits, labels),
                        lambda: loss_function_2(logits, labels))
```